# Linking entities in react

Tags: reactjs, typescript, pointers

I have a ts react app that pulls some objects from mongoDb. Those have id-based links between them, and I'm trying to simplify the way the relations are followed.

I'm expecting my state to result in four collections populated with the objects, which would be pointing at each other. I have Students, Workshops, Subscriptions and Payments. Subscriptions associate a student with a workshop and payments are linked to a subscription. I expect to be able to call:

```js
a_student.name              
// A string

a_student.subscriptions()
// The student's subscriptions

a_student.subscriptions()[0].workshop().subscriptions()  
// This students first workshop's subscriptions

a_student.subscriptions()[0].workshop().subscriptions().map(s => s.student().name)
// The names of all of this student's first workshop's fellows
```

I have to retrieve the raw backend data and then "hydrate" it, building links between the entities.

I have a `useBackend` hook in which I export a function that pulls the raw data and a `ready` boolean that gives green light to render the UI

I hoped to handle the hydrating phase with a `useEffect` depending on an intermediate boolean state `dataLoaded`.

**The problem is that I get a lock situation** in which the lookup functions get closed over what are still empty lists. I'd like to have my links lookup the updated lists, such that for example the student's subscriptions function picks up the new student's subscriptions without having to modify the student (which is the scenario I'm trying to improve).

```js
  const useBackend = () => {

    // State and interface definitions for both cable-data buffer and hydrated elements lists

    const pullBackend = async () => {

      const raw_students = await pullStudents()
      const raw_workshops = await pullWorkshops()
      const raw_subscriptions = await pullSubscriptions()
      const raw_payments = await pullPayments()
  
      if(!raw_students || !raw_workshops || !raw_subscriptions || !raw_payments) {console.error(`Something went wrong`); return; }
  
      setStudentsBuffer(raw_students)
      setWorkshopsBuffer(raw_workshops)
      setSubscriptionsBuffer(raw_subscriptions)
      setPaymentsBuffer(raw_payments)
  
      setDataLoaded(true)
    }
  
  
    useEffect(() => {
      if(dataLoaded){
        
        const getMember = <T>(collection: Collection<T>) =>
        (_id: MongoId) => {
          console.log(`Looking up _id ${_id} in collection:`)
          console.log(collection)
          return _.find(collection, e => e._id == _id)
        }
    
        getStudent = getMember(students)
        getWorkshop = getMember(workshops)
        getSubscription = getMember(subscriptions)
        getPayment = getMember(payments)
    
        const hydrateStud: Hydrator<StudentCable, Student> = a => ({
          ...a,
          subscriptiones: () => subscriptions.filter(i => i._student == a._id),
          payments: () => payments.filter(m => (m.reason == "single class" || m.reason == "subscription") && m._student == a._id)
        })
    
        const hydrateSubs: Hydrator<SubscriptionCable, Subscription> = i => ({
          ...i,
          _student: i.student,
          _workshop: i.workshop,
          student: () => getStudent(i.student)!,
          workshop: () => getWorkshop(i.workshop)!,
          started: new Date(i.started), 
          pagos: payments.filter(m => m.reason == "subscription" && m._subscription == i._id)
        })
    
        const hydrateWork: Hydrator<WorkshopCable, Workshop> = t => ({
          ...t,
          _subscriptions: t.subscriptions,
          subscriptions: () => subscriptions.filter(i => i._workshop == t._id),
          started: new Date(t.started)
        })
    
        const hydratePaym: Hydrator<PaymentCable, Payment> = m => ({
            ...m,
            _student: m.student,
            student: () => getStudent(m.student),
            _workshop: m.workshop,
            workshop: () => getWorkshop(m.workshop),
            date: new Date(m.date),
            occasion: new Date(m.occasion)
          })
    
        setStudents(studentsBuffer.map(hydrateStud))
        setWorkshopes(workshopesBuffer.map(hydrateWork))
        setSubscriptiones(subscriptionesBuffer.map(hydrateSubs))
        setPayments(paymentsBuffer.map(hydratePaym))
    
        setReady(true)
      }
    }, [dataLoaded])

  }
```

What's a mechanism I could use to either delay the lookup in the collections until a call is made?